# How do I install/import module to python on mac

Tags: python, macos, module, package, root-framework

I haven't used python since my undergrad days so I'm incredibly rusty. I'm trying to install CERN's `ROOT` module. It's already installed on the mac terminal but I wish to access it in python too. I have it saved in site-packages which I have checked is the correct directory where all of my other accessible modules: numpy, scipy, matplotlib etc are housed.

Folder is called rootpy and includes the `__init__.py` file along with the `ROOT.py` and `ROOT.pyc` files, and other files, but when I try to import it under name `rootpy` or ROOT I receive the error:

> ImportError: No module named rootpy

or,

> ImportError: No module named ROOT

Does anybody know how to import the package?

Comment: did you use `pip` to install it ? I think putting code in correct directory is not enough.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39363/how-do-i-install-root-cern

Comment: Hi there, I did try to use `pip` and also tried `easy_install` but both threw up an error ``module` object has no attribute `module``. Tried `from rootpy import rootpy` in case it was a problem with class but it just said there was no module.

Comment: https://alexpearce.me/2013/12/root-on-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: I've already got the program running on the standard mac terminal, just really want to be able to run it through python. Looks like I'm not the only one havin trouble looking at the comments on that article, thanks for the links.

Comment: do i understand correctly, that in a terminal you can call the command `root` and the root c interpreter starts? Then, if the installation includes `pyroot` (when building root, the `PYTHON` flag needs to be set to true) you should be able to start `python` and call `from ROOT import TH1F`. If your root build has python enabled is visible when you call `root-config --config` from the command line. If it is, i suggest to check your environment (call `echo $PYTHONPATH`, it should contain `/where/root/is/installed/lib` - which you can confirm with `root-config --libdir`).

Comment: also, `rootpy` is something different than using root in python (which is usually called pyroot) it is a thirdparty product to enhance the interplay between root and numpy&others. rootpy does not come with root, you need to install it separately (e.g. with `pip` or `brew` or whatever you use for your installations of numpy, etc)